# Can I call an function from another function in Django views.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have created two functions in my views.

`def Covid_view()` - this one will fetch all covid data from an api.

Another function is `def home()`. Inside this function I want to call covid_view() which will return me data that I can pass in my template.

Below is my code:

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

# this function is just to call api and get data of covid
def covid_data():
    api_response = requests.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/india')
    covid_data = (api_response.json())
    trim_last_update = covid_data['lastUpdate']
    trimmed_date = trim_last_update.find('T') # Here I'm trimming date_time string to show only date. T was for time to I split till T and store prior string
    res_trimmed_date = trim_last_update[:trimmed_date] # This will print string till T but not T and afterwards
    confirmed = covid_data['confirmed']
    recovered = covid_data['recovered']
    deaths = covid_data['deaths']
    context = {
        'res_trimmed_date': res_trimmed_date,
        'confirmed': confirmed['value'],
        'recovered': recovered['value'],
        'deaths': deaths['value']
    }
    return context


def index(request):
    # here I want to call this function which must return me data so I can pass it to my template
    data = covid_data()
    return render(request, 'covidStatsApp/index.html', data)
```

When I tried to run it gives me error like even though I tried to pass request as well.

```
TypeError at /
covid_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: I think django always need a request argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All views take an `HttpRequest` object as their first parameter. It should be `def covid_data(request)`. That should fix it.
You can get more info about it in the official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/).

Edit: From what I know, you should always return an HttpResponse. You might have to format the returned data like `return HttpResponse(context)`. I haven't tried it and I'm talking from what I remember, but I think you get the idea. The documentation I cited before should have more info on this.

Answer (score -1):

```
def covid_data(request):                                                          
      .......                                                                                           
      ...                                                                             
      return context                                                               


def index(request):                                                               
    # here I want to call this function which must return me data so I can pass it to my template                                                       
    data = covid_data(HttpRequest)                                                 
    return render(request, 'covidStatsApp/index.html', data)
```

#That is All...